# Sorting a stream of files by their size

Tags: java, file, sorting, java-stream

I'm trying to get top-5 largest files in some file tree and I'm confused how to properly sort them in a stream. The thing is I have no clue where to get the parameter that my sorting should be based on.

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/stanislav/test"))) {
    stream
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing())
        .limit(5)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This is the only code chunk I could come up with. I do understand that I'm dealing with `Stream` of type `Path`. Is there any way I could transform that and do the task in a stream fashion? If so, what do I do to have my sorting line operate on the file size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a file length to comparator:

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/stanislav/test"))) {
    stream
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.toFile().length(), Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .limit(5)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

`Comparator.reverseOrder()` is used to sort in descending order.

Comment: Blazing fast and straight to the point! Thank you a lot! You saved the day.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/stanislav/test"))
     .sorted((o1, o2) -> Long.signum(Files.size(o1) - Files.size(o2)))
     .limit(5)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

with IO exception handling for `Files.walk` and `Files.size`.

`Files.size` uses non-blocking I/O.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the task at hand by extracting the length of the file with `toFile().length()`.

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/stanislav/test"))) {
      stream.sorted(Comparator.comparingLong((Path path) -> path.toFile().length())
                              .reversed())
            .limit(5)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```